# Nested loop in batch, splitting string and then splitting each token

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My ultimate goal is to take a string like "a.b;c.d;e.f.g" and perform an operation on each token delimited by ';', which includes a for loop that separately processes each subtoken delimited by '.'

I have split the origin input like so:

```
FOR %%i IN (%input%) DO (
  ECHO %%i
)
```

This seems to work but now I can't use the `:.=;` syntax to get %%i ready to be split again. I have tried `SET iVar=%%i` to then be able to use this syntax but the SET doesn't work, `iVar` remains empty. I do have EnableDelayedExpansion set.

To clarify, if loop variables were just normal variables in batch my final script would be something like this:

```
FOR %i% IN (%input%) DO (
  ECHO %i%
  FOR %j% in (!i:.=;!) DO (
    ECHO %j%
  )
)
```

and the output would be

```
a.b
a
b
c.d
c
d
e.f.g
e
f
g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "$input=a.b;c.d;e.f.g"
for %%a in (%$input%) do (
   echo %%a
   set "$int=%%a"
   set "$int=!$int:.= !"
   for %%b in (!$int!) do echo %%b)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I actually was trying this solution earlier but thought `set $int=%%a` wasn't working because I was using `%` instead of `!` later on.